# set visibility in forloop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop

I have a question about a for loop and setting the visibility  of `numericupdowns` to `true`. This is what I want to accomplish:

```cs
nud1.Visible = true;
nud2.Visible = true;
nud3.Visible = true;
nud4.Visible = true;
nud5.Visible = true;
nud6.Visible = true;
nud7.Visible = true;
nud8.Visible = true;
```

and this is how I was trying to do it:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  nud[i].Visble = true;
}
```

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: If nud8, etc., is a control, then look at indexing the controls collection on the form. You can index with the control name as a string.

Comment: You can put them in  aList<T>, an array or a Dictionary. But C# is not a script language, so variable names can't be constructed like you did..

Answer (score 2):

Put your controls into an array.

```
var controls = new Control[] { nud1, nud2, nud3, nud4, nud5, nud6, nud7, nud8 };

foreach (var c in controls)
{
    c.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: When in doubt (meaning always) prefer List<T> over array ;-)

Comment: I think it is good advice to "when in doubt, use `ToList()` instead of `ToArray`", as it results in fewer allocations in many places. But that does not mean you should prefer a `List<T>` over an array when creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Controls[name]` of the parent control:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
{
     Controls[$"nud{i}"].Visble = true;
}
```

Comment: Assuming the Parent has no other controls. Or use Linq with a where and/or a typeof cluase..

Comment: it accepts the control names, so doesn't matter if it has other controls or not

Comment: If `nud9` control is in a panel, your solution won't reach it.